# Split react router keeps matching 404 route on all routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Split my routes into two (for now, going to be four later) separate components.

```
const RouterComponentOne = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/routeA" component={ComponentA} />
      <Route path="/routeB" component={ComponentB} />
    </Switch>
  )
}

const RouterComponentTwo = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/routeC" component={ComponentA} />
      <Route component={Component404} />
    </Switch>
  )
}

const RouterDefault = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <RouterComponentOne />
      <RouterComponentTwo />
    </>
  )
}

export default RouterDefault;
```

When visiting any route from `RouterComponentOne` the `404` component is rendered (which it shouldn't). It renders on non-existent routes (example `/test/123/abc` which is correct, and doesn't render on any `RouterComponentTwo` route.
I added some dummy components to the `RouterDefault` and the `404` component rendered on all additional paths as well.

In short, the `404` route isn't matched/rendered within the routes of the component where the 404Route is. If put into the `RouterComponentOne` it won't render on `routeA` and `routeB` but will render for `routeC`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a property called `exact`

```
const RouterComponentOne = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/routeA" exact component={ComponentA} />
      <Route path="/routeB" exact component={ComponentB} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
```